# understanding why Wasserstein is weak

Tags: general-topology, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem, total-variation

I am reading [Wasserstein GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875) paper and in Appendix A, it says

> Let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a compact set (such as $[0, 1]^d$ the space of images). We define Prob($\mathcal{X}$) to be the space of probability measures over $\mathcal{X}$. We note $$C_b(\mathcal{X}) = \{f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}, f \text{ is continuous and bounded}\}.$$ Note that if $f \in C_b(\mathcal{X})$, we can define $||f||_\infty = \max_{x \in \mathcal{X}} |f(x)|$, since $f$ is bounded. With this norm, the space $(C_b(\mathcal{X}, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ is a normed vector space. As for any normed vector space, we can define its dual $$C_b(\mathcal{X})^* = \{ \phi: C_b(\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}, \phi \text{ is linear and continuous} \}$$ and give it the dual norm $||\phi|| = \sup_{f \in C_b(\mathcal{X}), ||f||_\infty \le 1} |\phi(f)|$.

> With this definitions, $(C_b(\mathcal{X})^*, ||\cdot ||)$ is another normed space. Now let $\mu$ be a signed measure over $\mathcal{X}$, and let us define the total variation $$||\mu||_{TV} = \sup_{A \subseteq \mathcal{X}} |\mu(A)|$$ where the supremum is taken all Borel sets in $\mathcal{X}$. Since the total variation is a norm, then if we have $\mathbb{P}_r$ and $\mathbb{P}_\theta$ two probability distributions over $\mathcal{X}$, $$\delta(\mathbb{P}_r, \mathbb{P}_\theta):= ||\mathbb{P}_r - \mathbb{P}_\theta||_{TV}$$ is a distance in Prob($\mathcal{X}$).

> We can consider $$\Phi: (\text{Prob}(\mathcal{X}), \delta) \to (C_b(\mathcal{X})^*, ||\cdot ||)$$ where $\Phi(\mathbb{P})(f) := \mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mathbb{P}}[f(x)]$. The Riesz Representation theorem ([Kakutani](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968778), Theorem 10) tells us that $\Phi$ is an isometric immersion. This tells us that we can effectively consider $\text{Prob}(\mathcal{X})$ with the total variation distance as a subset of $C_b(\mathcal{X})^*$ with the norm distance.

> The norm topology is very strong. Therefore, we can expect that not many functions $\theta \mapsto \mathbb{P}_\theta$ will be continuous when measuring distances between distributions with $\delta$...Now all dual spaces have a strong topology (induced by a norm), and a weak* topolgy. As the name suggests, the weak* topology is much weaker than the strong topology. In the case of Prob($\mathcal{X}$), the strong topology is given by the total variation distance, and the weak* topology is given by the Wasserstein distnace (among others).

Here are my questions:

1. I know what Reisz Representation theorem is (but not sure what [7](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968778), Theorem 10 is referring to) but I'm not sure what isometric immersion is and how Riesz Representation tells us that $\Phi$ is an isometric immersion.
2. I'm not too familiar with strong topology and weak* topology. Do certain norms induce different types of toplogies?
3. the paper says that norm topology is very strong and not many functions $\theta \mapsto \mathbb{P}_\theta$ will be continuous when measuring distances between distribtuions with $\delta$. I don't quite understand why a strong topology implies that not many functions will be continuous. Shouldn't strong topology contain more continuous functions than weak topology?